# How to position a button in bottom right corner of MapView in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to wrap my head around flexbox, and also how the component tree works with a `react-native-maps` MapView (and whether that's different from other components with components "on top of them" for which I'm currently using `Callout`.

For example, here's my `MapView`'s render method. The `TouchableOpacity` area (and its `buttonCallout` container. is currently just for my experiments in understanding layout. I'm using the `F8StyleSheet` wrapper from makeitopen.com

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          region={this.state.region}
          showsUserLocation={true}
        >
          {this.renderMarkers()}
        </MapView>
        <Callout style={styles.searchCallout}>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={searchText => this.setState({ searchText })}
            onSubmitEditing={this.handleSearch.bind(this)}
            style={styles.calloutSearch}
            placeholder={"Search"}
            value={this.state.searchText}
          />
        </Callout>
        <Callout style={styles.buttonCallout}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.touchable]}
            onPress={() => console.log("press")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.touchableText}>Press Me 1</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[styles.touchable]}
            onPress={() => console.log("press")}
          >
            <Text style={styles.touchableText}>Press Me 2</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </Callout>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = F8StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  buttonCallout: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: "flex-end",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    ios: { padding: 5 },
    borderRadius: 20
  },
  touchable: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    padding: 10,
    margin: 10
  },
  touchableText: {
    fontSize: 24
  },
  searchCallout: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)",
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: "80%",
    marginLeft: "5%",
    marginTop: 40
  },
  calloutSearch: {
    borderColor: "transparent",
    marginLeft: 10,
    width: "90%",
    marginRight: 10,
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 0.0
  }
});
```

It makes sense how I use margins to get the `searchCallout` to be where I want it to be because it's at the top.

As the code is now, the `buttonCallout` (with the `TouchableOpacity` inside) renders in the top right corner (sensible - `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` puts it at the "end", on the right).

...

Mid-post update! By changing the `styles.container`'s `flexDirection` to `row`, with the buttons callout at `alignSelf: flex-end`. I've got the button callout on the bottom, and the search callout is still on top. I guess `Callout` components all render on top of each other.

So now I can use `justifyContent` on `styles.container` to have *both* callouts either in the center or on the left or right (`center, flex-start, flex-end`). How do I justify the different items separately? (`justifySelf` is not a thing!)

Wrapping both callouts in a unstyled `View` component results in the button callout rendering at the top-right but the search callout being nowhere to be found.

Wrapping them both in a callout results in the buttons rendering a little right of the top left corner, with the search callout again not displayed.

Help me understand all this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you're trying to position the `buttonCallout` at the bottom, give it a `postion:'absolute'`, so it will stay at the bottom

```
buttonCallout: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection:'row',
    position:'absolute',
    bottom:10,
    alignSelf: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 20
  },
```